# javascript array mix by two keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of 3 (or more) different types and groups:
Lets say colors and shapes, I want to spread that item as much as possible (not random)

```
['blue', 'green', 'red']
['circle', 'rect', 'tri']
```

they are organized in an array

```
[
  {type: 'blue', group: 'circle'}, {type: 'blue', group: 'rect'}, {type: 'blue',group: 'tri'},
  {type: 'green', group: 'circle'}, {type: 'green', group: 'rect'},
  {type: 'red', group: 'circle'}, {type: 'red', group: 'rect'}, {type: 'red',group: 'tri'},
]
```

I'm trying to sort it in a way that two different groups or types won't follow each other and also the group will follow (circle,rect,tri):

```
[
  {type: 'blue', group: 'circle'}, {type: 'green', group: 'rect'}, {type: 'red',group: 'tri'},
  {type: 'green', group: 'circle'}, {type: 'red', group: 'rect'}, {type: 'blue',group: 'tri'},
  {type: 'red', group: 'circle'}, {type: 'blue', group: 'rect'},
]
```

I was tying to go with several different ways, mapping the groups then types, mapping types then groups.

The idea is to be able to display it on screen (react) as there won't be two type / groups one next to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working code, result is predictable and not random:

```
let types = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'black'];
let groups = ['circle', 'rect', 'tri'];

let result = [], index1 = 0; index2 = 0;
let totalResult = types.length * groups.length;
for (let i = 0; i < totalResult; i++) {
    result.push({type: types[index1], group: groups[index2]});
    index1++;
    index2++;

    // Reset counter
    if (index1 === types.length) index1 = 0;
    if (index2 === groups.length) index2 = 0;
}

console.log(result)
```

And the output meet your requirement. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I don't think `sort` will works in this case, so my idea is make the result mixed when pushing value into it.

Comment: I Ended up with something very close to your answer, so i accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` loop on array which need to be ordered (`shapes`) and calculate the index of `colors`.

```js
const shapes = ["circle", "rect", "tri"];
const colors = ["blue", "green", "red"];

const res = [];
colors.forEach((_, ci) => {
  shapes.forEach((group, si) => {
    const type = colors[(ci + si) % colors.length];
    res.push({ type, group });
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a brute force method by generating all possible pairs and then collect the pairs by avoiding duplicates with a backtracking algorithm.

```js
function getAllPairs(left, right) {
    var pairs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < right.length; j++) {
            pairs.push([left[i], right[j]]);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}

function check(array) {
    const sets = [new Set, new Set];
    return array.every(a => a.every((v, i) => !sets[i].has(v) && sets[i].add(v)));
}

function fill(result, pairs) {
    if (!pairs.length) return result;

    var left = result.slice(Math.floor(result.length / half) * half);

    for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        if (check([...left, pairs[i]])) {
            var newResult = fill([...result, pairs[i]], [...pairs.slice(0, i), ...pairs.slice(i + 1)]);
            if (newResult) return newResult;
        }
    }
}

var type = ['blue', 'green', 'red'],
    group = ['circle', 'rect', 'tri'],
    half = Math.sqrt(type.length * group.length),
    result = fill([], getAllPairs(type, group))
        .map(([type, group]) => ({ type, group }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```